# How to navigate to a new page from within a OnFrameNavigated handler

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, navigation, windows-store-apps

I am porting a Windows Phone 8 app to Windows Store 8.1 and I am having some trouble with navigating to a new page when Frame.Navigate(...) is called from within a OnFrameNavigated handler.

The long story:

The App manages different "Media" objects like Books or Films. To edit the properties (title, author, etc.) of such an element the WP uses a custom "MediaEditor" control that was inspired by the DatePicker from the WP ToolKit:

Instead of manually navigating to an Editor/Picker page the Editor/Picker is capsuled in its own class. This class hooks up to the ApplicationFrame and handles Navigation to the Editor/Picker page on its own. When the ApplicationFrame navigates back to the page/content that was visible before showing the Editor/Picker the result can be processed, e.g. fire an event with the picked date.

There is one difference in my MediaEditor compared to the DatePicker: 
If the MediaItem that is currently edited is related to another MediaItem (e.g. Movie A is the film version of Book A) the editing of this item can directly been started from within the MediaEditor:

- call mediaEditor.Edit(MovieA) --> MediaEditor for MovieA is displayed
- Select to Edit BookA from within MediaEditor --> MediaEditor for MovieA is closed and MediaEditor for BoolB is displayed

This is done by calling Edit(BookA) from within OnFrameNavigated. Thus the complete Navigation is:

- call mediaEditor.Edit(MovieA) --> Frame.Navigate(typeof(MediaEditorPage), MovieA)
- Select to Edit BookA --> Frame.GoBack()
- Detect that BookA should be edited in OnFrameNavigated --> Frame.Navigate(typeof(MediaEditorPage), BookA)

While this works on Windows Phone this does not work on Win 8.1. Frame.Navigate(typeof(MediaEditorPage), BookA) is simply ignored. There is no OnNavigationFailed, no console output, nothing. The App navigates back to the first page (the one that original called mediaEditor.Edit(MovieA)) and nothing else happens.

What exactly is the problem here?

```
MediaEditor mediaEditor = new MediaEditor();
mediaEditor.Edit(bookItem);


public class MediaEditor {
    private Frame applicationFrame;
    private object frameContentWhenOpened;


    public void Edit(MediaItem item) {
        applicationFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;


        if (applicationFrame != null) {
            frameContentWhenOpened = applicationFrame.Content;

            applicationFrame.Navigated += OnFrameNavigated;
            applicationFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;

            applicationFrame.Navigate(typeof(MediaEditorPage), item);
        }
    }

    void OnNavigationFailed(object sender, NavigationFailedEventArgs e) {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e);
    }


    MediaEditorPage editorPage;
    void OnFrameNavigated(object sender, NavigationFailedEventArgs e) {
        if (e.Content == frameContentWhenOpened) {
            applicationFrame.Navigated -= OnFrameNavigated;
            applicationFrame.NavigationFailed -= OnNavigationFailed;

            applicationFrame = null;
            frameContentWhenOpened = null;

            if (editorPage != null) {
                if (editorPage.EditOtherItem)
                   // Directly start editing another Item
                   Edit(editorPage.OtherItem);
                else
                   // Finish editing, fire Events, etc
            }
        } else {
            editorPage = e.Content as MediaEditorPage ;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: are you subscribing to NavigationFailed elsewhere? In this sample you unsubscribe before you try to navigate again

Comment: I unsubscribe from NavigationFailed in OnFrameNavigated. After this in OnFrameNavigated Edit(editorPage.OtherItem) is called and in Edit I re-subscribe to NavigationFailed. Thus during navigation NavigationFailed should be handeled.Even if I do not unsubscribe from the event the handler does not get called.